# Javascript showing number with leading zero

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I am new to javascript, while i was trying to test an example with below code,
Code:

```js
function sayHello(name, age) {
  document.write (name + " is " + age + " years old.");
}
```

```html
<p>Click the following button to call the function</p>  
<form>
   <input type="button" onclick="sayHello('abc', 010)" value="Say Hello">
</form>
<p>Use different parameters inside the function and then try...</p>
```

i am sending parameter as 'abc' and 010. But  in output I am getting like below,

Output:
abc is 8 years old

Comment: You should pass `010` as a string. or convert the age to string before you concatenate

Answer (score 3):

When JavaScript encounters a number preceeded by a 0, it assumes an octal is being used, hence the 8. As Eddie stated in the comments, the best way to avoid this would be by converting the number to a string by encasing it in quotations. Hope this example below helps!

Try

```
onclick="sayHello('abc', '010')"
```

and use + sign to convert the string to the number explicitly.

```
console.log('age: ' , +age); //print age: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `010`,  it gets treated as base `8` which is octal. The decimal representation of octal `010` is `8`. That is the reason you seeing `8`.

Either remove that zero or pass it as a string like below

```js
function sayHello(name, age) {
  document.write (name + " is " + age + " years old.");
}
```

```html
<p>Click the following button to call the function</p>  
<form>
   <input type="button" onclick="sayHello('abc', '010')" value="Say Hello">
</form>
<p>Use different parameters inside the function and then try...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javacript engines interpret leading zeros as octal number literals.It is defined in an appendix of [EMCA Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1)
010 becomes 8 * 1 = 8.